A Major is confused / lied too
Corporal Jones is told by his sergeant to take private Smith and go dig a big hole using hand shovels. Jones and Smith are not happy digging this big hole by hand. They feel it is best done using heavy duty construction equipment but it is a legal order that they much follow.
As it turns out, the private's first name is General. In addition, there is a major on the base that has the construction equipment needed to get the job done quickly. Corporal Jones
calls the major and tells him that General Smith wants a hole dug. He does not inform the major that the General Smith is a private. The major assumes that General Smith is a general not a private. The major then informs Corporal Jones that he will arrange for the  hole to be dug at once since he wants to keep generals happy. Within 90 minutes, a back hoe appears at the right location and the hole is dug.
Did Corporal Jones break military law?

There's always Article 134...

As worded, they have disobeyed the sergeant's orders by not using hand tools.  If you reword the hypothetical that the sergeant ordered them to dig a hole and simply handed them hand tools rather than ordering them to dig a hole with hand tools, then whether they broke military law comes down to whether tricking the major was unlawful.

@JustinCave being handed a shovel is an implied order to use those - which means the lawful order is "dig with these"

This post is based upon a true story that happened during WW2. The names  have been changed and the  number of men assigned to the  Corporal was also changed. In  the real world situation the corporal got away with  it.  Both the major and the sergeant did not  know what happened. I find it hard to believe that anybody was in danger of being shot. Being sent to the  stockade might be a possibility.

@Trish, "being handed a shovel is an implied order to use those"  Not necessarily.  Context and the Sergeant's intent are important here:  If the Sergeant's intent was to have the ditch dug for some purpose and didn't have access to machinery, he may not care how they ditch got dug and is merely providing his men with the only tools he has available.   If instead the manual labor is punishment for showing up late, well... that's a different scenario.  We don't have enough information to make that determination.

In certain circumstances, (i.e. if no deceit occurred) Cpl Jones could even be praised for resourcefulness and initiative...

@MichaelHall the crucial point is the deception reg "General Smith" here. If the order was "We need a trench. Get to work men, we have... shovels there!" that invites ingenuity (but also implies the troop needs to dig till the equipment is there to speed along everything)

I understand the element of deception, that doesn't negate my point.

Both Privates Smith & Corporal Jones
10 USC 890 / UCMJ Art. 90 Wilfully disobeying superior Command
First of all, Private Smith & Corporal Jones were under a direct and specific lawful order to dig the hole with shovels. By not digging with shovels, both violated the direct order to dig with shovels.
The punishment depends on how much each knows and circumstances: If Smith suggests it to Jones, then he is wilfully disobeying too, if he is oblivious that his name is used, he is unpunishable.
The two should deem themselves lucky if there is no war going on, because that stunt could get them executed during a war - if the court martial deems that the proper punishment for getting heavy equipment. While I could not find a single case for this, the law provides for it, though much more typically, military lawyers explain it as:

Service members guilty of Article 90 violations face the maximum possible punishment of dishonorable discharge, forfeiture of all pay and allowances, and confinement for up to 5 years.  If the violation occurred during a time of war, the accused may also be subject to the death penalty.

The death penalty would be extraordinary against the record, but it practically is on the table. The manual for court martial has a three columns on this article (at IV-24), explaimiung among others:

(d) Specificity of the order. The order must be a
specific mandate to do or not to do a specific act. An
exhortation to “obey the law” or to perform one’s
military duty does not constitute an order under this
article.

As described, Shovels were mandated. If they were handed with the order, they were implied and still mandated. If just "Dig a trench!" was ordered, the specificity would go away.

(f) Nature of the disobedience. “Willful
disobedience” is an intentional defiance of authority.
Failure to comply with an order through heedlessness,
remissness, or forgetfulness is not a violation of this
article but may violate Article 92.

Yet, there's also some light in the tunnel: you could not charge them if digging the hole did not serve any military purpose or mission goal. Too bad that keeping the lads busy or training their shoveling skill for the trench line is a military purpose.

(iv) Relationship to military duty. The order
must relate to military duty, which includes all
activities reasonably necessary to accomplish a
military mission, or safeguard or promote the morale,
discipline, and usefulness of members of a command
and directly connected with the maintenance of good
order in the Service. The order may not, without such
a valid military purpose, interfere with private rights or
personal affairs. However, the dictates of a person’s
conscience, religion, or personal philosophy cannot
justify or excuse the disobedience of an otherwise
lawful order. Disobedience of an order which has for
its sole object the attainment of some private end, or
which is given for the sole purpose of increasing the
penalty for an offense which it is expected the accused
may commit, is not punishable under this article.

Corporal Jones alone
Assuming that the above isn't used, Jones also has possibly broken these four (or even more):
10 USC 892 Failure to obey order or regulation
There's likely a standing order or regulation that you have to use a person's rank in communication, and to not use first names unless absolutely necessary. If acting as a messenger - to make sure the receiving officer knows who is the sender.
10 USC 889 Disrespect toward superior commissioned officer[...]
By implying the Private was a general, that shows disrespect to the Major, and any real General Smith on base.
10 USC 891  Insubordinate conduct toward warrant officer, noncommissioned officer, or petty officer
Trying to pass along the order of the Sergant to another soldier is insubordination.
10 USC 906 Impersonation of officer, noncommissioned or petty officer, or agent or official
Making it appear that Private Smith is a general makes it impersonation.

Obtaining the assistance of others in order to more efficiently comply with a lawful order would not meet the common definition of insubordination.  Nor would respectfully requesting equipment from the Major meet the definition of disrespectful behavior.  It is possible to omit certain facts in a very respectful manner.

@MichaelHall it does if you claim to have the order of a general.

I disagree per the definitions you have linked to.
